# Change what/how the Twitter account tweets

Tags: feature-request, twitter

It would be nice if the Twitter account pulled any images from questions to make them more attractive to Twitter users and also included more information about the question other than the title.

I realize the account is likely a bot, but perhaps someone could handpick questions. Even if there are fewer tweets, it would be nice... maybe it could show kind of the "best of [site] Stack Exchange."

Specifically, I'm asking in terms of the @StackChemistry account, but I'd like to present this as a broader feature request: 
[image]

Tweet that I think would bring more traffic/increase retweets:

[image]

Comment: One problem here is that we don't necessarily have the rights to those images. We know we have the rights to the title & text; we can safely use it.

Comment: @Undo: How would SE *not* have the rights to the images, if they're being displayed in the post anyway?